# Getting second IP from Ethernet iface works, WiFi does not work

Tags: vlan, iproute2

Physical interface:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ip addr show enp1s0
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:68:3b:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.0.204/24 brd 172.20.0.255 scope global enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2e0:4cff:fe68:3b6f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Commands issued:

```
ip link set dev enp1s0 promisc on
ip link add link enp1s0 address 02:cd:ab:00:10:02 wan0 type macvlan
ip link set dev wan0 up
dhclient wan0
```

Voila:

```
10: wan0@enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/ether 02:cd:ab:00:10:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.0.119/24 brd 172.20.0.255 scope global wan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::cd:abff:fe00:1002/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Now, do the same things with the WiFi interface:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ip addr show wlp3s0
4: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:e5:f9:30:c4:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.3.111/24 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global wlp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::76e5:f9ff:fe30:c4ec/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Commands issued:

```
ip link set dev wlp3s0 promisc on
ip link add link wlp3s0 address 02:cd:ab:00:10:01 wan1 type macvlan
ip link set dev wan1 up
dhclient wan1
```

dhclient hangs out for a while and logs: "No DHCPOFFERS received" which leaves me with this final unsatisfying result:

```
9: wan1@wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/ether 02:cd:ab:00:10:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::cd:abff:fe00:1001/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Any thoughts as to why the virtual WiFi interface with its own unique MAC cannot get an IP address assignment? How does this differ from the wired card?

Regards and Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wi-Fi is strictly point-to-point with *one* MAC address per station. Only with WDS (proprietary with anything but obsolete encryption) does it support the so-called 4-address mode which enables multiple MAC addresses per station.

As such, macvlan can never work with Wi-Fi links. Use something else like the awesome ipvlan.

Comment: 4addr mode association (WDS bridging) doesn't require obsolete encryption. It's WDS repeater mode that does. (And, well, the _old_ "wds" interface mode in Linux does, but it's been superseded by 4addr.)

Comment: WDS repeating is just a regular AP interface bridged to a station interface in WDS mode. There’s no magic involved except 4-address mode.

Comment: And in particular there's no magic that would prevent the use of WPA2, is there?

Comment: No, except most access points don’t run standard Linux with `hostapd`. Modern 4-address mode *might* work. However, it much more likely it will not.

Comment: @DanielB what an absolutely annoying restriction

Comment: thank you for the comment about ipvlan. very easy to use indeed and handy for containers or vms when there's only wireless available